# RegExp to find a specific string not ending with a specific word

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to figure out a RegExp to match the following strings...

1. MyClassSetupEngine
2. MyClassExecuteEngine
3. MyClassDatalog

but not the specific string

1. MyClassSetup

Notice the string #1 includes the string #4 but #1 should be found by the RegExp while #4 should not.

I tried the following (with no success so far):

`MyClass(^(Setup).+)`

`MyClass(?!(Setup).+)`

**EDIT** I'm using C++ with boost regexp 1.35.0

Comment: I think MikeC has a correct answer but just for the sake of it, you have to used modifiers set so "." does NOT match newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
MyClass(?!(Setup$)).+
```

The dollar sign signifies the end of the string.

[Note, this works for Javascript - what language are you using?]

Comment: I'm using C++, i'll add it to my question

Comment: According to [this doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), boost uses perl regex syntax by default, so I think this should work... let us know.

Comment: looks good to me - just had to set "." does not match newlines

Comment: @Mike: i'm back from a vacation - thanks, it worked (missed the $ sign...)